# Integer programming, system of linear inequalities.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am woring on a problem and I got these inequalities.

$t_{01}+t_{11}+t_{21}\ge 4$

$t_{02}+t_{12}+t_{22}\ge 4$

$t_{10}+t_{11}+t_{12}\ge 4$

$t_{10}+t_{01}+t_{22}\ge 4$

$t_{10}+t_{02}+t_{21}\ge 4$

$t_{20}+t_{21}+t_{22}\ge 4$

$t_{20}+t_{01}+t_{12}\ge 4$

$t_{20}+t_{02}+t_{11}\ge 4$

There are $8$ integer unknowns, $t_{ij}\ge 0,  0\le i \le2, 0\le j \le2, t_{00}$ is missing. Every unknown is used in exacly 3 inequalitites. The problem is to find solution that minimizes sum of all $t_{ij}$.

If we sum all inequalities will get

$3\times \sum \ge 8\times 4$

$\sum \ge 11$

I have got this solution 
$t_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
       & 2 & 2  \\
    2  & 2 & 0  \\
    2  & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$ and I need hint to prove that it optimal. Sum of all unknowns is $12$ here. Maybe linear programming method can be used?

Comment: This can be solved as a MIxed Integer Programming (MIP) problem. It is so small any MIP solver will do (even Solver inside Excel will suffice).

Comment: I will try a solver but anyway I hope to find an analytic solution.

Comment: I think analytic solutions are difficult. I ran with a MIP solver and got 12 as proven optimal objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

Let one of $t_{ij}$ be $2$ (if there is $3$, using same idea we can even prove that sum is $\ge13$).

Let $t_{02}=2$.

If $t_{01}=0$ then $t_{10}+t_{22}\ge4$ and $t_{11}+t_{21}\ge4$ and $t_{12}+t_{20}\ge4$ so sum of all $t_{ij}\ge 2 + 0 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 14$

If $t_{01}=1$ then $t_{10}+t_{22}\ge3$ and $t_{11}+t_{21}\ge3$ and $t_{12}+t_{20}\ge3$ so sum of all $t_{ij}\ge 2 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12$

If $t_{01}=2$ then $t_{10}+t_{11}+t_{12}\ge4$ and $t_{20}+t_{21}+t_{22}\ge4$ so sum of all $t_{ij}\ge 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 = 12$

So for all cases we have sum of all $t_{ij}\ge 12$.